# Could not get input device information

Tags: android

From the crash log,it's caused by TransactionTooLargeException, but I didn't exchange huge data use intents, services or the IPC transaction. I got this problem for a long time, help me to solve this odd bug, I appreciate that.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not get input device information.
at android.hardware.input.InputManager.getInputDevice(InputManager.java:221)
at android.view.KeyCharacterMap.load(KeyCharacterMap.java:334)
at android.view.KeyEvent.getKeyCharacterMap(KeyEvent.java:2799)
at android.view.KeyEvent.getUnicodeChar(KeyEvent.java:2856)
at android.view.KeyEvent.getUnicodeChar(KeyEvent.java:2832)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.isTypingKey(ViewRootImpl.java:5610)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkForLeavingTouchModeAndConsume(ViewRootImpl.java:5648)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.access$1600(ViewRootImpl.java:138)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$EarlyPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4373)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$EarlyPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4358)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4020)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4074)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4043)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4183)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ImeInputStage.onFinishedInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4343)
at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$PendingEvent.run(InputMethodManager.java:2257)
at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.invokeFinishedInputEventCallback(InputMethodManager.java:1907)
at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.finishedInputEvent(InputMethodManager.java:1898)
at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$ImeInputEventSender.onInputEventFinished(InputMethodManager.java:2234)
at android.view.InputEventSender.dispatchInputEventFinished(InputEventSender.java:141)
at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:138)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException
at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
at android.hardware.input.IInputManager$Stub$Proxy.getInputDevice(IInputManager.java:569)
at android.hardware.input.InputManager.getInputDevice(InputManager.java:219)
... 28 more
android.os.TransactionTooLargeException
at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
at android.hardware.input.IInputManager$Stub$Proxy.getInputDevice(IInputManager.java:569)
at android.hardware.input.InputManager.getInputDevice(InputManager.java:219)
at android.view.KeyCharacterMap.load(KeyCharacterMap.java:334)
at android.view.KeyEvent.getKeyCharacterMap(KeyEvent.java:2799)
at android.view.KeyEvent.getUnicodeChar(KeyEvent.java:2856)
at android.view.KeyEvent.getUnicodeChar(KeyEvent.java:2832)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.isTypingKey(ViewRootImpl.java:5610)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkForLeavingTouchModeAndConsume(ViewRootImpl.java:5648)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.access$1600(ViewRootImpl.java:138)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$EarlyPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4373)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$EarlyPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4358)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4020)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4074)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4043)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4183)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ImeInputStage.onFinishedInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4343)
at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$PendingEvent.run(InputMethodManager.java:2257)
at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.invokeFinishedInputEventCallback(InputMethodManager.java:1907)
at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.finishedInputEvent(InputMethodManager.java:1898)
at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$ImeInputEventSender.onInputEventFinished(InputMethodManager.java:2234)
at android.view.InputEventSender.dispatchInputEventFinished(InputEventSender.java:141)
at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:138)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: add some relevant code also

Comment: @SuhailMehta some code?what's the meaning?

Comment: I encounter the same crash .device is Android 5.0.2 (21)，samsung:SM-A7009:armeabi-v7a

Comment: Same on Huawei MediaPad T1 with Android 4.4.

Comment: getting same error.